# C - store to null pointer error, segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, encryption, segmentation-fault, cs50

Please bear with my code. I'm a beginner in C. The code below builds a Vigenere cipher. The user inputs a `key` argument which is used to encrypt a `plaintext` message. The code will output the `ciphertext`.

The error I receive is as follows. Note that I have not studied pointers yet.

Any help in diagnosing the error would be greatly appreciated!

```
vigenere.c:47:13: runtime error: store to null pointer of type 'char'
Segmentation fault
```

The code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]){

// check for 2 arguments
if (argc != 2){

    printf("missing command-line argument\n");
    return 1;

} 

// check for character argument
int i,n;

for (i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++){

    if (!isalpha(argv[1][i])){

        printf("non-character argument\n");
        return 1;

    }

}

// if previous 2 checks are cleared, request 'plaintext' from user

printf("plaintext:");

// declare plaintext, key, and ciphertext

string t = get_string();    // plaintext
string u = argv[1];         // key (argument)
string y = NULL;            // ciphertext

// encode plaintext with key -> ciphertext

for (i = 0, n = strlen(t); i < n; i++){

    if (tolower(t[i])){

        y[i] = (char)((((int)t[i] + (int)tolower(u[i%n])) - 97) % 26) + 97;

    } else {

        y[i] = (char)((((int)t[i] + (int)tolower(u[i%n])) - 65) % 26) + 65;

    }


}


printf("ciphertext: %s\n", y);

}
```

Comment: You attempt to dereference a null pointer and write to it? That should be pretty clear. And if you don't know about pointers then why are you *using* them? [Get a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read. Learn first, use later.

Comment: `string y = NULL;` --> `string y = calloc(strlen(t)+1, sizeof(char)); `

Comment: `n = strlen(t); i < n;` : Use a different variable name for `n` here.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please avoid using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `97` you mean the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) character `'a'` then *say* so. Or better yet, since you want to convert between upper and lover case use [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) and [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower). You already use `toupper` but wrongly, you should be using [`isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) instead.

Comment: Regarding pointers, the type-name `string` is an alias for `char *`. It is a pointer type. This is one of the bad things about CS50 and its library, it makes you believe that you're not using pointers when in fact you are. While the CS50 library do hide some of the complexities of C, it does so to the detriment of learning C properly IMO.

Comment: `if (tolower(t[i])){` --> `if (islower((unsigned char)t[i])){`

Comment: Get into the habit of using `valgrind` against your code. Use a `lint` checker outside of the compiler as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yep, and if you really need a magic number, but you don't know why you need it or why it has it's value, name it `strange_magic_number` or something.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude *And if you don't know about pointers then why are you using them* That is because he doesn't know he is using pointers! The cs50 and it's "string" type strikes again!

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yeah I noticed the CS50 part later. In my oppinion, learning from CS50 is almost worse than learning from "online judges".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wait? People __learn__ from online judges?

Comment: Thanks for all your input. I'll consult the books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error message because variable `y`is `NULL`.

Type `string` is actually a `typedef` (an alias in other words) to `char *` which means "pointer to `char`" therefore `y` is a pointer to char.

When you are doing `y[i]`, you dereference a `NULL` pointer which is not allowed and leads to an error. `NULL`represents a non-existing memory space so you can not store your ciphertext here !

To solve this problem you can declare and initialize `y` as follows :

```
char *y = calloc(strlen(t) + 1, sizeof(char)); // Ciphertext, ready to hold some data !
```

*You will have to `#include <stdlib.h>`in order to use the `calloc()` function.*

Now, `y` is a pointer to a memory space as large as `t` (plaintext and cyphertext have the same size) that you can dereference and write data to !

You should definitely learn about pointers and how memory works before going any further. Some programmer dude posted a great list of books in the comments of your original post,  take a look at it !

Comment: Thanks! This really helped.